# instance of show variables

Tags: haskell

Is it possible to use a variable like below?

```
instance Show Box where
        show (Contents x y z) = "Contents " ++ x ++ " items, " ++ y ++ " items and " ++ z ++ " items"
```

This doesnt compile, have i added the string together wrong, or this generally not possible?

Im trying to write a show function that has the following effect;

EXAMPLE: show (Contents 2 4 5) results in the string "Contents 2 boxes, 4 parcels and 5 letters".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you have something like this:

`data Box = Contents Integer Integer Integer`

Since `Integer` has a `Show`-instance, just try the following: (And BTW, using `(.)` here, is more efficient than using `++`)

```
instance Show Box where 
  showsPrec _ (Contents x y z) = showString "Contents " . shows x . 
                                 showString " items, " . shows y . 
                                 showString "items and " . shows z . 
                                 showString "items"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and your implementation is correct, but make sure that `x`, `y` and `z` are `String`s first. (If not, `show` them.)

Comment: X Y Z would be numbers, is that a problem

Comment: `(++) :: String -> String` Appends strings, not ints, which is a problem that `Show` solves. `show 1 ++ show 2 == "12" :: String`